# Smallest Lipschitz constant for $f(t,y)=Ay$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, lipschitz-functions

Let $f(t,y)=Ay$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for a symmetric Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. What is the smallest Lipschitz-constant for f w.r.t. y, i.e. $\|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)\|_2 \le L\|y_1-y_2\|_2$ according to the eigenvalues of $A$ and is it correct that the smallest one-sided Lipschitz-constant is $\lambda_{max}$ of $\frac12 (A+A^T)$? Can someone help me?

Comment: What does it have to do with t?

Comment: @Vim sorry, but I don't understand your question

Comment: Does it work like this: $\|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)\| = \|Ay_1-Ay_2\| = \|A(y_1-y_2)\| = \|A\|\|y_1-y_2\| \le L\|y_1-y_2\|$ and then $L=\|A\|$ is the smallest constant?

Comment: It does indeed work like that, however do note a small mistake you have made in second to last step. Taking $||A||$ out makes for a $\leq$ not a equality. EDIT: in order to convince yourself, consider the case when $y_1$ is one of the eigenvectors and $y_2 =0$. When is $A(y_1 - y_2)$ maximal in that case?

Comment: @mathmatix since $t$ doesn't enter the function, you may just write $f(y)$ instead of $f(t,y)$ imo.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk thank you!

Comment: @Vim yes you're right.